# is it possible to define an interface in prisma?

Tags: go, graphql, prisma

I am trying to have a `"generic"` info in my object.

Basically what I want to do is to have 2 different kinds of object, lets say `image` and `document`

Both have different fields except for the `ID`

I was wondering what would be the best approach to define my `datamodel.prisma` so when I use my graphql model (in GO) I can use a generic interface like `data`

Is it even possible? If not what solution could be the best?

I know in graphql there are interfaces but Im not sure how to define it in prisma.

Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interface and union types are not currently supported in Prisma (see feature requests [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/83) and [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma2/issues/253)).

Comment: could be a possible solution for this?